# Python printing ever other letter of a word

Tags: python

Write a program that asks the user for a word and then prints out a new word containing every other character of the word (including the first one).

Examples of what your program should print if given various inputs:

input: "helloworld"

output: hlool

Comment: Perfect. What have you tried?

Comment: not sure where I am supposed to begin

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: There are many posts here on the subject. Go through a few, code, come back with a solid question when stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Remembered a better solution:

```
s = "helloworld"
s[::2]
```

Output:

```
hlool
```

And if you wanted the odd letters:

```
s[1::2]
=> 'elwrd'
```

Comment: Nice short solution, way better than mine haha

Answer (score 0):

You can do with with modulus and a loop like this.

```
out = "" # Having the empty string for the result
for i in range(len(myString)): # Looping over the string 
    if(i == 0 or i % 2 == 0): # If it's the 1st or 3rd etc character
        out += myString[i] # Add the character to the output
print(out) # This will be your desired output.
```

Output: `hlool`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but sure.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you don't need the extra check for `i==0`, as `0%2 == 0`

Comment: Wasn't sure if checking `0 % 2` would yield 0 so I stuck it in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def everysecond(string):
    ret = ""
    i = True  
    for char in string:
        if i:
            ret += char
        if char != ' ':
            i = not i
    return ret
print (everysecond("helloworld"))
```

Output will be:

```
hlool
```

On every iteration `i` changes its value to `True` if was `False` and vice versa. It does this for every character in the string passed into the function `everysecond()`. If `i==True` then the character is assigned to `ret`. At the start `i` is `True` and therefore the first character is always included.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using conditions:

```
s = "helloworld"

param = 2
newString = "".join(s[i] for i in range(0,len(s),param))
print(newString)
```

Output:

```
hlool
```